# How to communicate Catalyst and Node.js

Tags: javascript, perl, node.js, catalyst

How to communicate between node.js and perl Catalyst applications?

I have two applications: Node.js and Catalyst.

Now these two applications communicate each other by HTTP. But it's not fast and secure way.

What another way to communicate its, like local unix socket or other?

What perl modules and node.js packages can i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

[ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org) - [Node binding](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3anode-js); [Perl binding](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings%3aperl)

[dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) - [perl dnode protocol support](https://github.com/substack/dnode-perl)

Lots of possibilities for message transport (e.g. RabbitMQ) and network communication... but it sure would be nice to stick with HTTP (on top of SSL/TLS) for all of support that will come with it.

Comment: All of these two applications hosted at the same server. No network communication (local) is well for me =)
Also i need only send data between its

Comment: I suppose you could write a native node extension that uses libperl++ or even spawn perl scripts from node, but this seems like vastly more trouble than it is worth.  The network communication protocol abstractions (technology agnostic) make it possible for you to bridge the language stacks with the added benefit of loosely coupling the two applications.  My recommendation stands, even for local dependencies (when bridging node.js -> perl).

Comment: ZeroMQ is cool! Thanks! It makes my application very flexible and extensible in the future

Answer (score 1):

It's too much to write a full answer about your problem, since I haven't worked with Catalyst since a long time ago, but here you go a simple working UNIX Socket perl-server, node-client proposal

Server :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -T

use strict;
use IO::Socket::UNIX;
use threads;

my $socket_path = "/tmp/test_socket";
unlink($socket_path);

my $socket = IO::Socket::UNIX->new(
    Local  => $socket_path,
    Type   => SOCK_STREAM,
    Listen => 1,
);

die "Can't create socket: $!" unless $socket;

print "waiting for connections\n";

while (1) {
    my $client;

    do {
        $client = $socket->accept;
    } until ( defined($client) );

    my $thr = threads->new( \&processit, $client )->detach();
}

sub processit {
    my ($client) = @_;

    if($client->connected){
         print $client "Hello from server\n";

         while(<$client>) { print "$_\n" };
    }
    close( $client );
}
```

Client :

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var net = require('net'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    sock;

var c = net.createConnection('/tmp/test_socket');

c.on('connect', function(socket) {
    console.log('connected');
    c.write("Hello from NodeJS");
    c.on('data', function(data) { console.log('perl: '+data.toString()) });
});
```